# Tensor product of cohomology of discrete spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to show that for two infinite sets $X$ and $Y$ endowed with the discrete topology, the external product
$$-\times -\colon H^0(X)\otimes H^0(Y)\to H^0(X\times Y) $$
is not an isomorphism.

I am not really sure where to start on this one. I think I understand the product structure: for $\alpha\in H^0(x)=\operatorname{Hom(\mathbb{Z}^{|X|}, \mathbb{Z})}$ and $\beta\in H^0(Y)=\operatorname{Hom(\mathbb{Z}^{|Y|}, \mathbb{Z})}$ the product is given by $(\alpha\times\beta)(x,y)=(p_1^*\alpha\cup p_2^*\beta)(x,y)=\alpha(x)\beta(y)$ where the last expression is multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$.